# Datagrid not printing properly on IE browser but fine on Firefox and Chrome

Tags: internet-explorer, printing, datagrid, asp.net-1.1

I did some research on Google and it seems that Datagrid that stretches past a page will have part of it cut off when it is printed on IE browser.

One of the suggested solution is to upgrade to .Net 2.0 from .Net 1.1 but at the moment it is not a viable option.

I've a few Datagrids. Each follow the other and may stretch across one page printing size.

Is there any viable solution so these Datagrid tables do not get cut off when getting printed from IE?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed this issue.

Just need to make sure all the datagrids on the page are placed in **one HTML table**. Then they will all print properly from IE browser.

```
        <table style="WIDTH: 690px">
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <div id="div1">
                            <table style="WIDTH: 690px">
                                <tbody>
                                    <tr>
                                        <asp:datagrid ... ></asp:datagrid>
                                    </tr>
                                </tbody>
                            </table>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <div id="div1">
                            <table style="WIDTH: 690px">
                                <tbody>
                                    <tr>
                                        <asp:datagrid ... ></asp:datagrid>
                                    </tr>
                                </tbody>
                            </table>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
```